# How to use an IFrame with a page that uses LocalStorage?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, local-storage

I've two websites on different servers. The first one runs on localhost, in a machine that I provide to users. The second one runs on my remote server. Since I need to update the website that locally runs, I create the website to be just an IFrame to the remote one.

So my use case is a User that goes on localhost:9000, see a login page but it is actually an IFrame of the remote page.

The problem happens when the remote page tries to access to local storage. Even if I don't need to store on localhost local storage, I instead need to store on remote local storage so that, when the user will go on the remotoServerDomain.com is already logged in.

I was able to do that before Chrome started to block, by default, the third-party cookies (https://www.searchenginejournal.com/chrome-84-3rd-party-cookies/374529/).
Indeed, disabling the block of that cookies, all still work but, since the block is now enabled by default, I started to receive many tickets due to generated errors.

Do you know if I can fix it in some way? Maybe specifying to use the same local storage of the remote server so to don't run in cross-domain storage?

My last idea is to catch the error so to notify the user about that, so to permit him to choice if to change browser or disable, for a while, the security setting.